# Partitioning disk image file

Tags: fedora, partition, parted

I want to partition a raw disk image with the following commands:

```
#creating the blank image
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=example.img bs=1M count=50

#write the partition table
$ parted example.img mktable msdos

#creating partition but not the file system
#creating fat32 primary partition 1 to 15 MB
$ parted example.img mkpart p fat32 1 15
#creating ext3 primary partition 16 to end
$ parted example.img mkpart p ext3 16 -0
```

These commands don't create a file system. How could I do that? I am trying the `mkfs` command in `parted` but it is showing **no command found**. How could I create file system externally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the command `kpartx` to create a loopback device that can then be formatted.

```
kpartx -a /path/to/imagefile.img  # Presents partitions from the image file
mkfs.vfat /dev/mapper/loop0p1   # Format partition 1
mkfs.ext3 /dev/mapper/loop0p2   # Format partition 2
kpartx -d /path/to/imagefile.img  # Unmaps the partitions from the image file
```

[Related kpartx examples here](http://tinyapps.org/docs/mount_partitions_from_disk_images.html)

Answer (score 3):

Recent versions of `losetup` gained `-P` option. Quote from [man 8 losetup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/losetup.8.html):

```
-P, --partscan
          Force the kernel to scan the partition table on a newly created loop device.
```

Doing `losetup -f my_partitioned.img` not only creates `/dev/loop0`, but also partition devices:

```
$ ls -l /dev/loop0*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   7, 0 Oct  5 18:43 /dev/loop0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 0 Oct  5 18:43 /dev/loop0p1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 1 Oct  5 18:43 /dev/loop0p2
```

Answer (score 1):

With the usual mkfs commands, such as `mkfs.ext4`.  You will need to use `losetup` to associate a loopback device with the file though in order to have somewhere to point mkfs to.  You also may need to use `partprobe` to recognize the partitions on the loop device.